# Cannot install devtools properly without digest R

Tags: r, devtools

I upgraded to R version 3.4.3 and I am no longer able to install and use `devtools` - due, it seems, to a problem with installing `digest`. I receive the following error:

```
install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘BiocInstaller’ is not available
also installing the dependency ‘digest’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.4/digest_0.6.15.tgz'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.4/digest_0.6.15.tgz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.4/digest_0.6.15.tgz'
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘digest’ failed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.4/devtools_1.13.4.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 439078 bytes (428 KB)
```

I have uninstalled and re-installed R, upgraded RStudio, manually removed `devtools` and tried to re-install. I am on Mac 10.12.6 Sierra. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To overcome this problem, you can simply run: `install.packages("digest", type = "source")`.

Answer (score 0):

Run `install.packages("digest", type = "source")`. It is documented on the `digest` GitHub.